# How to change the command line in process list?

Tags: node.js

How does nginx appear in the process list like this?

```
$ ps -ef | grep nginx
... S     9:16   0:08.43 nginx: worker process
... Ss    9:16   0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
```

I want to change my CLI program's process name in node.js.

Comment: I suspect this question belongs on another SE site, perhaps SuperUser.

Comment: This question needs some background as to what you've tried or what you want to do.  Also how does node.js play into this?

Comment: @devshorts: None of the language tags seem to fit in.

Comment: @devshorts I hope my CLI programe child it process name.

Comment: In the C language, you can use `printf` to make columns.  In C++, see the `setw` stream manipulator.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: the title is "how change cmd line in process list"

Comment: @Electro: Yes, but the tags were C and C++, so I answered from that perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Node.js you can change [`process.title`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_title) to set the process' title shown in `ps`.

Comment: thanks, but I found OSX can not use process.title